# Problems when loading cameraimages in imageView

Tags: android, image, imageview, loading

When I take a picture, the picture will saved on the SD.(This works very well)

But the picture won´t shows in the imageView. Do you have any idea?

```
package de.example.Camera;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Cam extends Activity {
private Uri fileUri;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.b_cam);


    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.photo);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Start ActivityTwo
            /*
             * Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
             * ActivityTwo.class); intent.putExtra("MyStringValue",
             * editText1.getText().toString()); startActivity(intent);
             */
            try {
                PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
                boolean doesHaveCamera = packageManager
                        .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA);

                if (doesHaveCamera) {
                    // start the image capture Intent
                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                            MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    // Get our fileURI
                    fileUri = getOutputMediaFile();
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "There was an error with the camera.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 100) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (intent == null) {
                // The picture was taken but not returned
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        "The picture was taken and is located here: "
                                + fileUri.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();


            }else {
                // The picture was returned
                Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
                ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                imageView1.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) extras.get("data"));
            }
        }
    }
}

private Uri getOutputMediaFile() throws IOException {
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(
            Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            "DayTwentyNine");
    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
            .format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
            + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");

    if (mediaFile.exists() == false) {
        mediaFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        mediaFile.createNewFile();
    }
    return Uri.fromFile(mediaFile);
}

}
```

In the manifest I have are the following:

```
uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" 
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I have this peace of code that works fine the first function open the camera and take the picture and the second one place the image you took into an image view...

```
public void takePictu(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
}


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        photo3 = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(photo3);
        imageView.buildDrawingCache();
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        photo3.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); //bm is the bitmap object
        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();

        encodedImage = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(b, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
    }
}
```